# Can't connect TCP transport for host: localhost/127.0.0.1:4444 and Connection is refused to connect

Tags: java, jmeter, perfmon

I'm trying to verify the server health monitor for the app which is there in my local host. I'm getting below response. Please take a look into this once and help me out. In View Result tree HTTP Request showing response as 200.
Application: Through Jmeter
Application hosted : Java 11
Metrics: Perfmon

```
2021-06-16 12:47:04,032 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2021-06-16 12:47:04,033 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-06-16 12:47:04,034 INFO k.a.j.p.PerfMonCollector: PerfMon metrics will be stored in C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\perfmon_4504784525335490183.jtl
2021-06-16 12:47:04,038 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2021-06-16 12:47:04,068 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2021-06-16 12:47:04,068 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2021-06-16 12:47:04,069 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-06-16 12:47:04,069 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2021-06-16 12:47:04,070 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2021-06-16 12:47:04,070 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2021-06-16 12:47:04,070 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2021-06-16 12:47:06,002 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2021-06-16 12:47:06,003 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2021-06-16 12:47:06,004 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2021-06-16 12:47:06,006 ERROR k.a.p.c.AbstractTransport: Error during exit
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:138) ~[?:?]
    at kg.apc.perfmon.client.StreamTransport.writeln(StreamTransport.java:50) ~[perfmon-2.2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.perfmon.client.AbstractTransport.disconnect(AbstractTransport.java:63) [perfmon-2.2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.NewAgentConnector.disconnect(NewAgentConnector.java:36) [jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.shutdownConnectors(PerfMonCollector.java:281) [jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.testEnded(PerfMonCollector.java:149) [jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.testEnded(ResultCollector.java:345) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:218) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:493) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
2021-06-16 12:47:06,024 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Comment: There is no 'connection refused' here. The peer, whatever it is, has disconnected while you are still sending to it. Probably you have sent something it didn't understand.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please improve the title of your question so that it is useful for other having a similar problem or knowing a remedy. (Having the title contradict the quoted error message is *not* useful.) See [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

What is your platform ?

If your running on Linux, its possible to find what processes have actually opened a tcp port by doing  `lsof -a -i4 -i6 -itcp`

This will tell you what port your application has actually opened

Comment: Mine is Windows machine and it's just a sample application which I'm running on machine. This application I'm calling using localhost:8080. And the port is 4444.

Comment: OK You can still get a list of open ports by running the netstat command ,see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-active-network-connections-in-windows/

There are many reasons why you look a the list off ports e.g. , has another application open that port, has your application opened a different port instead of the one that you told it to open etc.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter PerfMon Metrics Collector is a Listener which talks to a special piece of software called [PerfMon Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) so in order to be able to collect machine performance metrics you need to install this Server Agent onto the machine you want to monitor

1. Download `ServerAgent-x.x.x.zip`
2. Unpack it somewhere
3. Use `startAgent.bat` script on Windows or `startAgent.sh` on Unix and derivatives to start the Server Agent
4. That's it, you should be able to configure PerfMon Metrics Collector to query the [metrics](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#supported-metrics) of your choice from the Server Agent

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes I did the same and ran the script by connecting by client and server. Once I ran my Jmeter script, immediately server is disconnecting and throwing the error.

Comment: Which error? If you're facing [this issue](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/issues/141) you need to replace sigar-amd64-winnt.dll with [this file](https://github.com/cnstar9988/sigar/raw/master/sigar-amd64-winnt.dll) (or re-build it yourself if you care about security

Comment: Thank you, I tried replacing the above mentioned dll in server agent and it worked for me well. Now I was able to measure the cpu and memory utilization without any issues.